# How to align buttons using a Grid Layout?

Tags: java, user-interface, textarea

Is it possible to use the Grid Layout for just your text area within the program and have your buttons outside of the grid layout for them to align how you want them ??

I'm struggling to align my buttons and I was wondering if this sort of problem is possible to solve using the grid layout or would I have to change my layout all together to see the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to use extra Composites with own layouts (e.g. one composite for text area with fill layout and other one for buttons with grid layout).
You can read [this good article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) about SWT layouts.

Comment: so its possible to have two layouts within your program ??. So one layout for the text area an the grid layout to align the buttons

Comment: @user3535064 , yeap, you can use several layouts in your app, but only one lyaout for one composite.